# VideoJS won't load video in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, video-streaming, html5-video

The system I am working on is set up like this:

Files (in DB) <-> ContentServer <-> Webpage

Say I have a link to a video, and someone clicks that link, the contentserver finds the requested file, generates a Guid to represent that file, and then builds a page which uses the Guid for the "file".  This Guid does not have a file extension (naturally).

When using VideoJS in IE and Firefox, this appears to work just fine.  However in Chrome it's not working at all.  The video doesn't appear to even be loading, much less loading and playing.  Below is an example of how I have it set up.  Anyone have any ideas how I could make this work on Chrome?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="/Video/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="/Video/video.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="/content/7cb55f87-b240-45e0-9890-ec383fd019c9"/>
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you paste the full URL of the video file directly into Chrome, what happens? Does it play?

Comment: Are you sure the video is being served with the proper MIME type? It should be `Content-Type: video/mp4`

Comment: The culprit appears to be the relative url in the src tag.  Changed that to absolute url and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem lies in Apple products and Google Chrome not playing nicely with ASP.Net. Chrome and Apple products first send a request for the first two bytes of content. If they don't receive these two bytes - they fail. ASP.Net does not have the capabilities to handle byte-range requests, regardless of whether or not the server it is on can. So, if you are using ASP.Net and you intend on using video, you should account for the fact that you will have to roll your own byte range request handler, or use one of a very few third party extensions that are out there.